# Most efficient way to find values “surrounding” X in a Collection?

Tags: swift, algorithm

Given an Collection like Array or Set, what’s the most efficient way to find the elements whose values “surround” X?  (i.e. closest value < X, and closest value > X)

For example:

```
    let numbers = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

    let result = numbers.closest(55) // returns something like (50, 60)
```

Comment: I don't know swift but probably in any language: Sort the array and keep track of the closest two values. I can't see any shortcut for this. If data is sorted, then might use some searching algorithms for searching the closest value(s), like binary search.

Comment: I’ve looked at Binary, but all the implantations I’ve seen return `nil` or throw an error unless X is present in the Collection. I guess I could alter those implementations to fit? What might that look like?

Answer (score 1):

If the array is unsorted, you can avoid sorting it (which would cost O(n log n)) using the following technique. If it is sorted, just use binary search.

You can do it in O(n) time and O(n) space (because we need a mutable copy of the array to work with) as follows:

```swift
func closest(_ values: [Int], target: Int) -> (Int?, Int?) {
    var values = values
    let index =  values.partition { $0 > target }
    return (values[0..<index].max(), values[index...].min())
}
```

I used optionals so that I could handle the case when where the target is either greater than the max in the array or less than the  min.

```swift
let numbers = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
var result = closest(numbers, target: 55)   // (Optional(50), Optional(60))
print(result)
result = closest(numbers, target: 200)      // (Optional(100), nil)
print(result)
result = closest(numbers, target: -10)      // (nil, Optional(0))
print(result)
```

---

For completeness, if your array is presorted, you can find what you're looking for in O(log n) using binary search, which would look something like this:

```swift
func closest(_ values: [Int], target: Int) -> (Int?, Int?) {
    var (l,r) = (0, values.count-1)
    while l < r {
        let m = l + (r - l) / 2
        if values[m] < target {
            l = m + 1
        }
        else {
            r = m
        }
    }
    return (values[l] < target) ? (values[l], nil) : (l > 0 ? values[l-1] : nil, values[l])
}
```